# Joining two tables where some columns merge and others must be null

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, outer-join

I feel like this question must have already been answered somewhere but my searching has not turned up anything relevant. If anyone is able to link to another answer I can accept this being marked as a duplicate and closed.

---

I have three tables like this:

```
users(id)
things1(id, user_id, thing1_text)
things2(id, user_id, thing2_text)
```

For the purpose of this example, assume there's only one user in the `users` table with an `id` of `1`.

Let's say `things1` looks like this:

<kbd>**`id`**

`1`

`2`</kbd>


<kbd>**`user_id`**

`1`

`1`</kbd>


<kbd>**`thing1_text`**

`im a thing 1`

`im a thing 1 too`</kbd>

And things2 looks like this:

<kbd>**`id`**

`1`

`2`</kbd>


<kbd>**`user_id`**

`1`

`1`</kbd>


<kbd>**`thing2_text`**

`im a thing 2`

`im a thing 2 too`</kbd>

I'm trying to create the query which will return this:

<kbd>**`user_id`**

`1`

`1`

`1`

`1`</kbd>


<kbd>**`thing1_text`**

`im a thing 1`

`im a thing 1 too`

`NULL`

`NULL`</kbd>


<kbd>**`thing2_text`**

`NULL`

`NULL`

`im a thing 2`

`im a thing 2 too`</kbd>

My first, admittedly naive, attempt looked like this:

```
select users.id as user_id
     , things1.thing1_text
     , things2.thing2_text
from users
full outer join things1
    on things1.user_id = users.id
full outer join things2
    on things2.user_id = users.id;
```

However this doesn't put `NULL` in any of the fields and instead combines them all - which I'm sure the more SQL minded among you probably figured when you read the query :D

Anyway. This is where I'm at. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want `union all`.  Start with this:

```
select user_id, thing1_text, thing2_text
from ((select user_id, thing1_text, NULL as thing2_text
       from things1 t1 join
            users u
            on t1.user_id = u.id
      ) union all
      (select user_id, NULL, thing2_text
       from things2 t2 join
            users u
            on t2.user_id = u.id
      )
     ) tt
order by user_id;
```

Comment: I noticed that your first answer performs about twice as fast as the edited one. Do you know why/what would cause that or why the edit would be preferable to the original?

Comment: After running both versions with an EXPLAIN it looks like it's using the indexes when I don't use a JOIN but not using them with the JOIN. I can only imagine this is postgresql making some kind of assumption about optimization due to the low number of rows in my test tables.

Thank's for the answer. This will get me started in the right direction.

Comment: @FrankJosephMattia . . . The first answer didn't use the `users` table for filtering.  That seems to be part of your question.